# Retrieving Session Attributes after Session Times Out

Tags: java, spring, session

I have a Spring MVC project setup where I define several model attributes & session attributes when a user accesses the home page `home.html`.

HomeController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getHomepage", produces = "text/html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
protected ModelAndView getHomepage(HttpSession session) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("home");
    // do some stuff
    session.setAttribute("attr1", "cool");
    session.setAttribute("attr2", "attributes");
    return mav;
}
```

I grab these session attributes on a separate `orderForm.html` (I'm using Thymeleaf as my template engine)

```
Session Attribute 1: <div th:text="${session.attr1}"></div>
Session Attribute 2: <div th:text="${session.attr2}"></div>
```

This works fine until my session is timed out/invalidated and the user is still on `orderForm.html` - they lose scope of the session attributes as they're defined only on the Home `@Controller`

Can I retrieve my session attributes without first hitting the homepage and without setting them on every view `@Controller` in my project?

Comment: Have you considered using interceptor to set the session attribute before displaying the home page? You can implement an interceptor for it and map it with the controller. Links: 1) http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/ 2) http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-interceptor-example/

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of Interceptors - will look into this thanks